# What is the best way to integrate your backend with CEF?

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I am currently trying to develop a Windows program using [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef-project/src/master/). So I want to integrate the backend in the app and then send the information to the UI via javascript bindings.

I have already integrated my project into CEF as it says in the instructions so like this:

- Create a new "myproject" directory in the root cef-project directory (e.g. "/path/to/cef-project/myproject").
- Copy the contents of the "third_party/cef/cef_binary_*/tests/cefsimple" directory to "myproject" as a starting point.

Only currently I don't know exactly how to integrate the backend into the code, because it has to run in an external thread, since CEF needs a thread? Or do I see this wrong (I am not yet so familiar with CEF and c++)? Does anyone perhaps have code examples of how to integrate their own c++ code into CEF?